# Interview question : Given two lists of different size, find a solution to have no more zeros in two lists, and the sum of the two becomes equal

Tags: python, list, optimal

I wonder if someone has a solution for this problem : Given two lists of different size, find a solution to have no more zeros in two lists, and the sum of the two becomes equal.

Input : Two lists of size n,m >= 0
Output : The two new lists, if it is not possible return -1

Example : l1 = [1,2,0,0,4]   l2 = [3,0,7]
Returns : l3 = [1,2,2,2,4], l4 = [3,1,7]

We have sum(l3) = sum(l4) and no more zeros in both list

Comment: What is the definition of "optimal" here? For example, why is `[1,1,1,1,1], [1,2,2]` not "optimal"?

Comment: @Kelly Bundy it could be that the 0s are kind of jokers to make the sum be equal (also the length of the lists stay the same)

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that the numbers replacing the 0s are integers between 1-9... otherwise infinite-many solutions.

Idea: `sum(l1_new) == sum(l1_new)` means that `sum(l1)+o1 == sum(l2)+o2` where `o1` and `o2` are the integers made of the partitions of the 0s. The sums of the old and new lists are constant and by rearranging the equation we get a *linear relationship* `o2 = s1 -s2 + o1`. Both `o1` and `o2` are subject to constraints depending on the amount of 0s per list (boundaries).

Finally use combination with replacements in order to include cases such as `3 = 1+1+1` where `1`... is repeated. If this condition is too relaxed use `itertools.combinations`.

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement


def c(l1, l2):
    L1, L2 = l1.copy(), l2.copy()

    s1, s2 = sum(l1), sum(l2)
    os1, os2 = l1.count(0), l2.count(0) # amount of zeros per list
    ds = s1-s2

    # boundaries - lower/upper
    lb1 = (os1 if os1 else 0)
    ub1 = (9*os1+1 if os1 else 1)
    lb2 = (os2 if os2 else 0)
    ub2 = (9*os2+1 if os2 else 1)
    
    # trivial partition - no zeros
    if os1 == os2 == 0:
        if s1 == s2:
            return l1, l2
        return -1
    
    # trivial partition - same amount of zeros
    if os1 == os2:
        if s1 == s2:
            return ([i if i else 1 for i in l1],
                    [i if i else 1 for i in l2])
        return -1

    # finding size of partition
    for o1 in range(lb1, ub1):
        o2 = ds + o1
        if lb2 <= o2 <= ub2:
            break
    else:
        return -1

    # partitioning of the integer
    po1 = next(c for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), r=os1)
               if sum(c) == o1)
    po2 = next(c for c in combinations_with_replacement(range(1, 10), r=os2)
               if sum(c) == o2)

    # replacing the zeros
    for n in po1:
        L1[L1.index(0)] = n

    for n in po2:
        L2[L2.index(0)] = n

    return L1, L2
```

Here some tests

```
ls = [
    ([1,2,4], [7]), 
    ([1,2,4], [8]),
    ([1,6,9], [8, 8]),    
    ([1,0,6,9], [8, 0, 8]),    
    ([0, 1,6,9], [5, 8, 8]),    
    ([1,2,4], [7, 0]), 
    ([1,2,0,0,4], [3,0,7]),
    ([9,2,0,4], [7,0,7]),
    ([1,2,0,0,4], [3,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 7]),
    ([0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0]),
    ([0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 9, 9]),
]

for l1, l2 in ls:
    o  = c(l1, l2)
    print(f"{l1}, {l2} -> {o}")
```

Output

```
[1, 2, 4], [7] -> ([1, 2, 4], [7])
[1, 2, 4], [8] -> -1
[1, 6, 9], [8, 8] -> ([1, 6, 9], [8, 8])
[1, 0, 6, 9], [8, 0, 8] -> ([1, 1, 6, 9], [8, 1, 8])
[0, 1, 6, 9], [5, 8, 8] -> ([5, 1, 6, 9], [5, 8, 8])
[1, 2, 4], [7, 0] -> -1
[1, 2, 0, 0, 4], [3, 0, 7] -> ([1, 2, 1, 3, 4], [3, 1, 7])
[9, 2, 0, 4], [7, 0, 7] -> -1
[1, 2, 0, 0, 4], [3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 7] -> -1
[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0] -> ([1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1])
[0, 0, 0, 0], [9, 9, 9] -> ([1, 8, 9, 9], [9, 9, 9])
```